# Changeable cookie expiry time

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

By default, the Identity 2.1 authentication cookie expiry time is set globally in `Startup.Auth.cs` via `CookieAuthenticationOptions`.
Is there a way to do that on-the-fly, depending on the user, so it's individually configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use `AuthenticationProperties` to specify the expiry at the time you call `SignIn`, like this.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Alice") };
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie");

var properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1) // One day expiry for Alice
};

Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(properties, identity);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. However there is one problem with the new Identity `SignInManager`: Overriding the `AuthenticationProperties` requires overriding `SignInAsync`, which is not pluggable. So need to verify override with every new release!